# Mapping additional media keys

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I have a wireless Apple keyboar, with no Fn key (the globe works as <kbd>Fn</kbd> key). But this is annoying for the way I have the media keys set up (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> for example).

Is there any way to map additional global keyboard shortcuts to the media actions. Like for example <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to Play/Pause, etc.

Comment: Do you also use the actual F-Keys **as** F-Keys, or just as 'Special Function' keys?

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, they are used mostly as F-keys. Otherwise I could just flip the checkbox and get the media keys directly, without any modifier keys.

Comment: I'd have a look at [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org) - it's not something I've used myself, but it seems very popular on AD for this type of task. [the Fn key is a really 'special' case, because it combines before it leaves the keyboard, making it it tough to intercept using the regular system prefs/hotkeys structure]

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks. Will check it out. However this keyboard does not even have an Fn key, but the "globe" key is used instead. Thus it should be possible to detect at the receiving end, that both keys are activated.